# Нет возможности написать сообщение Tetegram бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Имею проблему при вызове функции textMessage не срабатывает приглашение для ввода текста а сразу переходит в конец функции, в чем проблема.

Вот код функции

```
def textMessage(bot, update):
    k = str(update.message.text) #Вот здесь все нормально
    if k in final_user :
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        query = "SELECT password FROM student where email='%s'"%(k)
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        s1 = str(result)
        s2 = s1.replace("'", "")
        s2 = s2.replace("(", "")
        s2 = s2.replace(")", "")
        s2 = s2.replace(",", "")
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Password')
        password = str(update.message.text) #А вот здесь пропускает ввод
        if s2 == password:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Welcome!")
        else:
             bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Invalid password!")

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Invalid login!")
```

Весь код бота

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import pymysql
import apiai, json

updater = Updater(token='****')  # Токен API к Telegram
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
cnx = pymysql.connect(user='****',
                      password='****',
                      host='****',
                      database='****')


def startCommand(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text='Hello, I`m bot \n'
                          'Sing in please\n'
                          '/sign_in')

    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Login')



cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = "SELECT email FROM student"
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
final_result = [list(i) for i in result]
final_user = []
for i in range(len(final_result)-1):
    final_user.append(final_result[i][0])

print (final_user[1])



final_user = []
for i in range(len(final_result) - 1):
        final_user.append(final_result[i][0])



def textMessage(bot, update):
    k = str(update.message.text) #Вот здесь все нормально
    if k in final_user :
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        query = "SELECT password FROM student where email='%s'"%(k)
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        s1 = str(result)
        s2 = s1.replace("'", "")
        s2 = s2.replace("(", "")
        s2 = s2.replace(")", "")
        s2 = s2.replace(",", "")
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Password')
        password = str(update.message.text) #А вот здесь пропускает ввод
        if s2 == password:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Welcome!")
        else:
             bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Invalid password!")

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Invalid login!")




# Обработка команд

def helpCommand(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text='')


# Хендлеры
start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
help_command_handler = CommandHandler('help', helpCommand)
text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)
F_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)
# Добавляем хендлеры в диспетчер
dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(help_command_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(text_message_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(F_message_handler)

# Начинаем поиск обновлений
updater.start_polling(clean=True)
# Останавливаем бота, если были нажаты Ctrl + C
updater.idle()
```

Comment: У вас не срабатывает условие `if k in final_user:`?

Comment: этот if  cрабатывает все нормально

Comment: ну хз, я по крайней мере вижу странный костыль для обработки `result` -- можно ведь просто вызвать fetchone и у него запросить первый элемент -- password: `result = cursor.execute(query).fetchone()[0]` и в `result` будет ваш пароль, а эти `replace` выглядят жутким костылем и мб из-за них что-то и не работает. Кст, вы ведь могли на каждую строку добавить print'ы и отследить где пошло не так, как вы ожидали

Comment: Без  replace также пробовал не работает

Comment: Я вообще не уверен, что в той ветке кода что-то выполняется, поэтому и написал далее: `Кст, вы ведь могли на каждую строку добавить print'ы и отследить где пошло не так, как вы ожидали`

Comment: print вообще не работает